# Как сделать все ячейки в tableLayoutPanel одного размера?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. Моя цель - сделать все ячейки `tableLayout` одинакового размера, причём чтобы они оставались одинаковыми даже при добавлении/удалении столбца или строки. Пробовал сделать `AutoSize = true`, но это не помогло.

Собственно цель: во время выполнения программы пользователь вводит количество строк и столбцов, у меня создается соответствующий tableLayout, с полностью одинаковыми по размеру ячейками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дизайнер WinForms автоматически задаёт значения некоторым свойствам `TableLayoutPanel`, которые только мешают. Поэтому, для упрощения решения, предлагаю создавать его кодом вручную. Например, в конструкторе формы (но можно в событии `Form.Load`):

```
TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel
    {
        Parent = this,
        CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset,
        AutoSize = true,
        AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    };
}
```

В качестве родителя вместо формы (`this`) можно задать любой другой контейнер. `CellBorderStyle` я задал просто для наглядности, чтобы было видно ячейки.

Далее, где-то в коде задаём количество столбцов и строк:

```
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 5;
tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 3;
```

После чего назначаем столбцам и строкам стили с нужными размерами:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30));

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30));
```

`SizeType.Absolute` означает, что размеры задаются в пикселах.

Соответственно, при увеличении количества ячеек нужно добавлять стили для новых столбцов и строк. А можно изначально задать их с запасом.

---

Как вариант, вместо задания стилей, можно в каждую ячейку помещать контрол заданного размера, например, панель. Она раздвинет ячейку до своего размера:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 * 3; i++)
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Panel { Size = new Size(30, 30) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант:

```
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles[0].Height = 25;
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles[0].Height = 25;
```